# Leaving the country when applied for EAD

Tags: visas, usa, work

I will be accompanying my spouse(L1-Visa holder) on L2-Visa to Bay area in the month of June. From the documentation , it appears that it takes around 90 days to get a EAD on L2 Visa. I don't want to resign from India before I get a job and EAD  in US. Given this I have following questions :

1. During these 90 days, Can I appear in the interviews in US ?
2. During these 90 days, can I travel back/fro India after I am done applying EAD and biometrics is completed ? This is because I
   will resume my work in India after 15 days and would like to return
   back to US after I have my EAD in hand.
3. Can I continue to work in India holding an L2 visa and EAD application in progress?

Please confirm.

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't understand this question. You can appear in interviews in the US if you're in the US. Do you need to re-phrase?

2) Your EAD application does not affect your travel at all. Your visa is what counts, and there is nothing about an L2 visa that precludes travel. If your visa says (as it likely will) "entries M" you can travel in and out as you wish.

3) The US Government is not interested in what work you do outside the US. It is interested in any indication however that your visa application was not valid. Your travel pattern and time spent away from the US might be factors in this.

Comment: For #1, I think they meant is whether appearing in interviews a permitted activity on L2 without an EAD; like how employment is not permitted for people in certain statuses, and how studying is not permitted for people in certain statuses.

Comment: I see what you mean. If that's the case, there's nothing to stop one from attending job interviews, but it would be important to state that an EAD had not yet been granted, but was pending.